# when I press the button active in tableview

Tags: swift, uitableview

When I press the button, I want to run the Tableview cellForRowAt function. But I don't want to call cellForRowAt when I don't press the button. Because the cellForRowAt function works as soon as the application opens. Press the button and if newdevicechipnumber.ishidden == false I want to run the function in . I want that function to work when I press the Newdeviceadd button.

```
    class MainTableViewController: UITableViewController {

 let newdeviceadd: UILabel = {

        let topAlignment: SMIconLabel.VerticalPosition = .top

        let labelLeft = SMIconLabel()
        labelLeft.isHidden = true
        labelLeft.text = "Cihazı Ekle"
        labelLeft.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Black", size: 23)
        labelLeft.textColor = UIColor.flatWhite
        labelLeft.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        labelLeft.icon = UIImage(named: "homepage")    // Set icon image
        labelLeft.iconPadding = 5                  // Set padding between icon and label
        labelLeft.numberOfLines = 0                // Required
        labelLeft.iconPosition = ( .left, topAlignment )
        labelLeft.textAlignment = .left
        return labelLeft
    }()

    var items: [Device] = []
        var itemsnew: [NewDevice] = []

        let cellId: String = "cellId"

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! DeviceTableViewCell
            let selectedIndexPaths = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows
            let rowIsSelected = selectedIndexPaths != nil && selectedIndexPaths!.contains(indexPath)
            cell.accessoryType = rowIsSelected ? .checkmark : .none

            if newdevicechipnumber.isHidden == false {
                let deviceItemNew: NewDevice = itemsnew[indexPath.row]
                cell.new = deviceItemNew
                cell.titleNew.text = deviceItemNew.title
                cell.title1New.text = deviceItemNew.places
                cell.titlesaatNew.text = deviceItemNew.time
                cell.buttonNew.isOn = deviceItemNew.state
                cell.buttonNew.isHidden = hideBtn
                cell.buttonNew.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refreshDataNew), for: .touchUpInside)

             }

    }
```

Comment: Look into the documentation of `cellForRowAt ` and `didSelectRow`

Comment: It works right now, but I just want it to work when I push the button.

Comment: Are you asking how to make it so that the table view is initially empty and only starts to populate once you press a button?

Comment: Is the button inside each cell ? Or the button is outside the cells and you want it to refresh your tableview when it is pressed ? Please clarify your need.

Comment: the button is a button outside the cell that is outside the Tableview. When I Press this button, I want the tableview function to work. @rushelmet

Comment: Yes, that's all I'm asking. @rpecka

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to store some state in your ViewController and then flip that state once you push the button. If you do that, then you could tell your `numberOfRowsInSection` function to return zero if the button has not been pressed yet and return the true number if the button as been pressed.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1: You can use a `bool` to trigger the population of your `UITableView`. Let's say we call it `shouldPopulate`, and we define it at the top of your controller.**

```
var shouldPopulate: Bool = false
```

Use `shouldPopulate` to trigger the correct number of rows or `0`.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return shouldPopulate ? yourNumberOfRows : 0
}
```

Then when your button is tapped, you define `shouldPopulate` to `true` and reload the data.

```
@IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    self.shouldPopulate = true
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

**Option 2: You can use a `UIViewController` with a `UITableView` inside if you want to get specific a behavior, it would be better than `UITableViewController`.**

Instead of setting the `TableView Data Source` in `viewDidLoad` for instance, define it inside your action function.

```
@IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    self.tableView.dataSource = self
}
```

Setting data source should reload the data, you don't need to call `reloadData()`